# Laravel Javascript with Bootstrap Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a modal using Bootstrap on my Laravel project, I use my modal for looking up the detail of data. The data has many row at a table, each row of data has a button to pop up a modal. This is my Javascript code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="modal"]').click(function(e) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var url = $(this).attr("href");
      if (url.indexOf("#") == 0) {
          $(url).modal('open');
      } else {
        $.get(url, function(data) {
            $('<div class="modal hide fade">' + data + '</div>').modal().on('hidden', function(){
             $('.modal-backdrop.in').each(function(i) {
                $(this).remove();
            });
          });
        }).success(function() { $('input:text:visible:first').focus(); });
      }
    });
  }
```

When I click the button the modal pops up nice and the data comes out. But my problem is when I close the modal and click the other button, the data is the same as the first one I opened. I then try to reload the page and the data on the modal is always the data that I opened up first...
How do I fix it? Must I use AJAX?

Comment: attached an id attribute to the anchor element. say the index of the rows. From their use  the unique index attribute to show the content .

Comment: i give every links different url <a href= "{{route('advertiser-detailcampaign', $campaign->my_id)}}" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i></a>